# Cordova/Phonegapp - How to use Local Storage Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm using cordova for the first time to develop apps for android.
i have installed cordova local storage plugin.

But i don't know how to use it(what java-script code is to be used).
What i'm making is a To-do list app,so i need to store the strings or whatever the user inputs.

can anyone please post a short example demonstrating the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you exclusively that plugin need to be used or you can use other storage methods too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need localStorage plugin to use simple html localStorage.You can simply save and retrieve value without any plugin.

For saving:

```
localStorage.setItem("key",value);
```

for retrieving:

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

You can save upto 5mb per app with local storage.

You can use web sql too. [WEB SQL example link](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) It also does not need any plugin.

Then you can use a bit advanced SQL wrappers. This one needs plugin to be installed. [Brodysoft SQLite with complete documentation](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Comment: step by step implementation for sqlite plugin for cordova or ionic. http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2015/05/local-storage-with-sqlite-for-hybrid.html.